# Стёрла «с телефона» или «из телефона»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно: «она стёрла видео с телефона» или «она стёрла видео из телефона», и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"С" указывает на поверхность, с телефона можно стереть грязь или пыль. "Из" отсылает к содержимому или к принаджежности: "из памяти", "из учеников класса". В обиходе вариант "стёрла с телефона файл" широко распространён, хоть он и неправильный. Употребить можно при передаче прямой речи в художественном произведении. Но в грамотном тексте однозначно не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Принято говорить "снять на телефон", потому и "стирают с телефона". Однако, записывают номер в телефон, а удаляют из телефона. "Снять" выступает здесь в переносном смысле: "снимая" образ, мы копируем его и переносим, в действительности, в телефон, но наблюдаем на поверхности.  Так же в переносном смысле и "стираем", не вдаваясь в технические тонкости. Всё дело в нашем восприятии.

Answer (score 1):

*Стёрла видео с телефона* — ошибка. Видео находится в телефоне и удаляется из него. *Стереть* — не очень хороший вариант; думаю, не ошибочный, но стилистически сниженный.